# Postgresql - Regex to get all words in string without special characters except -

Tags: regex, postgresql, split

**Input**

```
Word-Word, Some other words    and this is another word et     another one
```

**Expected output**

```
Word-Word
Some
other
words
this
is
another
word
another
one
```

I have a table *(t)* with many strings like the one showed in the input.

**I'm trying to get every word in the sentence but the comas (','), the word *'and', 'et', 'und'* and of course every whitespace or sequence of whitespace that may be between words.**

**Regex that I'm using:**

1. Don't match whitespace `\\s+`
2. Don't match whitespace as long as special characters `((\b[^\s]+\b)((?<=\.\w).)?)` - **doesn't work in postgres for some reason**
3. Don't match a particular word `^(?!et$|and$|und$)` - **doesn't work either**

**Query that I'm running**

```
SELECT word FROM t, 
unnest(regexp_split_to_array(t.word, E'Missing expression')) as word;
```

Comment: you are genius man ! thank you again this is not the first time you answer one of my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an *extracting* approach here in the following way:

```sql
SELECT regexp_matches(
   'Word-Word, Some other words    and this is another word et     another one   ',
   E'\\y(?!(?:et|[ua]nd)\\y)\\w+(?:-\\w+)*',
   'g');
```

See the [online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d41324efea50e959560369e0a8a8f737). *Regex details*:

- `\y` - a word boundary
- `(?!(?:et|[ua]nd)\y)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `et`, `und` or `and` as whole words immediately to the right of the current location
- `\w+(?:-\w+)*` - one or more word chars and then zero or more occurrences of `-` and one or more word char sequences

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e9WqfI/1) (converted to PCRE).